# LINQ Any() argument versus parameter data type issues

Tags: c#, linq

I have an object with a string-typed parameter called '**baan_cat_fam_code**'.  The code below is my attempt to find all items in the query that have a **baan_cat_fam_code** that exist in a generic string list called **catFamCd**.

```
query = query.Where(r => r.baan_cat_family_code.Any(s => catFamCode.Contains(s)));
```

The problem is that this won't compile - I get an error that states

```
"Argument type 'char' is not assignable to parameter type 'string'"
```

for some reason the predicate **s** is typed as char.  So I append **.ToString()** to the argument in the **.Contains** method.  However, when the code runs, I get the following exception thrown when the result of the query is bound to a listbox.

```
"The argument 'value' was the wrong type. Expected 'System.Char'. Actual 'System.String'."
```

This has got me scratching my head.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem you're running into is that `baan_cat_family_code` is of type `string` which implements `IEnumerable<char>`.  When you call `Any` it's essentially saying

- Is the predicate true for any `char` in this `string`

What you really want to be asking though is

- Is this `string` in the list `catFamCode`

Try the following which does the latter

```
query = query.Where(r => catFamCode.Contains(r.baan_cat_family_code));
```

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `Any()` on a string which looks at its elements which are `chars`, hence the error.

You should have done:

```
query = query.Where(r => catFamCode.Contains(r.baan_cat_family_code));
```